# Integration, trigonometry, gamma/beta functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

In a classical mechanics text, I saw an integration(as part of a math) that uses gamma function as follows:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos^2 x-\cos^3 x)dx$$ $$=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{2+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{0+1}{2})}{2\Gamma(\frac{2+0+2}{2})}-\frac{\Gamma(\frac{3+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{0+1}{2})}{2\Gamma(\frac{3+0+2}{2})} $$
What is the exact formula that is used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and in particular its defining property:
$$\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}=B(x,y) =
  2\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin\theta)^{2x-1}(\cos\theta)^{2y-1}\,\mathrm{d}\theta,
  \qquad \mathrm{Re}(x)>0,\ \mathrm{Re}(y)>0$$

Comment: I really wonder why they make things so complex ! Cheers.

Comment: Indeed. Although I admit that it's quite an easy formula to remember, and I've always found it difficult to recall the exact values of the integrals of the powers of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and always end up having to calculate them from scratch

Comment: Can someone guide me into the steps?

Comment: Got it. Thanks.