# Closed form solution for $\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x dx$

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, closed-form, gamma-function, beta-function

I am trying to calculate Fourier series coefficients (by hand) and the integrals I need to solve are of the following type

$$I(N,M,n,m)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x dx,$$

in which $N,M,n,m \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. I tried to use WolframAlpha / Maple to come up with a general formula because doing all the $4^4$ cases would make it impossible for me to work with that list but both didn't give a result.

> It would be great if there was a way to obtain a simple closed form solution. If that is not possible is there a way to get very accurate approximation for $I(N,M,n,m)$?

Comment: Why does this have the [tag:asymptotics] tag?

Comment: I added it because of the approximation that I needed, do you mean that it is inappropriate?

Comment: I don't see how it's relevant at all. In what sense are you seeking an asymptotic?

Comment: I think that an asymptotic expression can also be used as an approximation. Like Stirling's approximation is actually is more of an asymptotic expression.

Comment: You're asking about a finite set of values. It doesn't make sense to ask for an "asymptotic" for that.

Comment: I will simply remove it.

Comment: Actually this an exact value no need of approximation see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I(N,M,n,m)=\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos^N x|\sin^M x\cos^n x\sin^m x dx \\+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x,dx$$
Set $u =x-\pi$

$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x,dx\\=\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^Mx |\cos^n (x+\pi)\sin^m (x+\pi),dx $$
So that 
$$I(N,M,n,m)=\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos^N x|\sin^M x\cos^n x\sin^m x dx \\+(-1)^{n+m}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x,dx$$

> **But $\cos(x+\pi) = -\cos x$ and $\sin(x+\pi) = -\sin x$ Hence,**

\begin{split}
I(N,M,n,m)&=&\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos^N x|\sin^M x\cos^n x\sin^m x dx \\
&+&(-1)^{n+m}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x,dx\\
&=&[1+(-1)^{n+m}]\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x,dx\\
 &=&[1+(-1)^{n+m}]\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^N x\sin^M x\cos^n x\sin^m x dx \\
&+&[1+(-1)^{n+m}]\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} |\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x dx
\end{split}

> **Setting  $ t= \pi-x$  and noticing that  $\cos(\pi-x) = -\cos x$ and $\sin(\pi-x) = \sin x$ We get ,**

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} |\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x dx = (-1)^n\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \cos^N x\sin^M x \cos^n x\sin^m x dx$$
 Therefore,

\begin{split}
I(N,M,n,m)&=&
 [1+(-1)^{n+m}]\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^N x\sin^M x\cos^n x\sin^m x dx \\
&+&[1+(-1)^{n+m}]\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} |\cos^N x||\sin^M x|\cos^n x\sin^m x dx\\
&=& [1+(-1)^{n+m}][1+(-1)^{n}]\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^N x\sin^M x\cos^n x\sin^m x dx
\end{split}
and
$$ [1+(-1)^{n+m}][1+(-1)^{n}]= [1+(-1)^{m}+(-1)^{n}+(-1)^{n+m}]$$

> Conclusion 
>   $$\bbox[yellow]{I(N,M,n,m) =[1+(-1)^{m}+(-1)^{n}+(-1)^{n+m}]\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{N+n} x\sin^{M+m} xdx }$$

Also note the following relation with Beta function and Gamma function \url{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_b%C3%AAta}.

$$\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} =B(x,y) = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2x-1} t\sin^{2y-1} tdt ,~~x>0,y>0$$

So that ,

$$\bbox[yellow]{I(N,M,n,m) =\frac{1}{2}[1+(-1)^{m}+(-1)^{n}+(-1)^{n+m}]B\left(\frac{M+m+1}{2},\frac{n+N+1}{2}\right)\\=\frac{1}{2}[1+(-1)^{m}+(-1)^{n}+(-1)^{n+m}] \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{M+m+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{N+n+1}{2}\right)}
{\Gamma\left(\frac{M+N+m+n+2}{2}\right)}}$$

Comment: +1: Excellent answer. This will save me a lot of trouble :D.

Comment: I edited your answer because I think there were some minor mistakes. In the Beta function definition and for the relationship between $\Gamma$ and $B$.

Comment: Cool no problem

Answer (score 1):

Hint: An easy way is to use the following identity which is *quite easy* to prove
[image]

which is an easy consequence of [Integration, trigonometry, gamma/beta functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981058/integration-trigonometry-gamma-beta-functions/1981073#1981073)

Comment: The problem with this formula is that I need to split the integral into 4 pieces. I knew this method, but I wanted a direct method (but not the closed formula for the integral). Without splitting. If no one comes up with a more compact solution I will accept your answer :).

Comment: Maybe you a look to my answer it give the relation with Beta function